# Should I translate URL for better SEO?

Tags: seo, google, url, multilingual

I have a website about TV shows, that for default (EN) pages, it's like this:

```
example.com/en/show/actors
example.com/en/show/episodes
```

The site is localized in different languages, and I was wondering if, SEO-wise, is better to localize page names too, like this:

```
example.com/it/serie/attori
example.com/it/serie/episodi
```

Or stick to original and default page names, like this:

```
example.com/it/show/actors
example.com/it/show/episodes
```

Comment: Do you have pages in different languages??

Comment: Yes. There are localized plots and information, based on the language selector in the URL.

Comment: If you have a page of a particular language, I do recommend using a URL/URI in that same language the best way you can. It is a heavy semantic clue for the page and translating the URL/URI will make search for these terms and page (in general) much stronger.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is more user friendly to translate slugs, but don't expect, it will bump your site's ranking like a bomb.

Google is able to translate URLs by itself, so it can match a meaning of a page with english URL and italian content.

URL translation could lightly improve your user metrics and user experience, which are ranking factors too.

Also, if you do it, do it for your users, not for Google. And if you have more important issues on your site, improve them first.